# How can I achieve this "join by between" SQL in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT `o`.*,
    (SELECT ROUND(`o`.`norm` * `sr`.`multiplier`, 2)) AS `time`,
    (SELECT ROUND(`c`.`rate` * `sr`.`multiplier`, 2)) AS `tariff`
FROM `operations` AS `o`
INNER JOIN `plan_structures` AS `ps` ON `ps`.`id` = `o`.`plan_structure_id`
INNER JOIN `plans` AS `pl` ON `pl`.`id` = `ps`.`plan_id`
LEFT JOIN `surcharges` AS `sr` ON `pl`.`pairs` BETWEEN `sr`.`pairs_min` AND `sr`.`pairs_max`
LEFT JOIN `class_rates` AS `c` ON `c`.`class` = `o`.`class`
```

How can I achieve this in EF Core?

1. My first idea was using DB view - this worked, but then I had to have views for all related tables for entity relationships in EF. I couldn't link both `Operation` and `OperationView` to `PlanStructure`.
2. My second idea was "somehow" join it by `BETWEEN` like in SQL, but I found that it's not possible (or is it?)
3. virtual columns - which are also not possible between independent tables.

So... is there any other way other than DB view?

My entities:

```
public class Plan
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Pairs { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PlanStructure> PlanStructures { get; set; }
}

public class PlanStructure
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Plan Plan { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Operation> Operations { get; set; }
}

public class Operation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Class { get; set; }
    public int Norm { get; set; }
    public double Time { get; } // computed somehow
    public double Tariff { get; } // computed somehow

    public PlanStructure PlanStructure { get; set; }
}

public class ClassRate
{
    public int Class { get; set; }
    public double Rate { get; set; }
}

public class Surcharge
{
    public int PairsMin { get; set; }
    public int PairsMax { get; set; }
    public double Multiplier { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: this should also work when `Operations` are included - when I do `context.Plans.Include(p => p.PlanStructures).ThenInclude(s => s.Operations);`, all of those operations should have those calculated properties.

Comment: Between is nothing more than a functionally equivalent way of writing where X greater than Y and X less than Z. Just use greater than and less than instead of between. You will have to join in a WHERE clause instead of a JOIN clause but that is also OK when you are using Linq. Pseudo code `from x in tableA from y in tableB.Where(s => s.val > x.val and s.val < x.otherval).DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: And how could I make it so I don't have to repeat those *greater / less than* in all my queries? I would like to have nice and clean `context.Operations.First();` and it would get me `Operation` entity with everything populated. It this possible?

Comment: Do you really need all those backticks in your SQL? I don't think you should have `Time` and `Tariff` (simple) properties in your `Operation` class - those are for columns that exist in the database. Instead, make them client side computed columns that query the Surcharge table when needed, or if it is small enough, cache the Surcharge table locally and reference that.

Comment: I'm using those backticks so it looks better with syntax highlighting, is there any problem with it? And client side querying wouldn't be good for me. I am retrieving list of those operations and all of them need to have those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEFT JOIN can be expressed as `Where(...).DefaultIfEmpty()`. Also `Math.Round` still does not have translation, so calculation is done on the client side.

```cs
var query = 
    from o in ctx.Operations
    from sr in ctx.Surcharges
        .Where(sr => o.PlanStructure.Plan.Pairs >= sr.PairsMin && o.PlanStructure.Plan.Pairs <= sr.PairsMax)
        .DefaultIfempty()
    join c in ctx.ClassRates on o.Class equals c.Class into gj
    from c in gj.DefaultIfempty()
    select new 
    {
        Operation = o,
        Rate = (double?)c.Rate,
        Multiplier = (double?)sr.Multiplier
    };

var result = query.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(e => new 
    {
        e.Operation,
        time = e.Multiplier == null
                ? (double?) null 
                : Math.Round(e.Multiplier.Value * e.Operation.Norm),
        tariff =  e.Multiplier == null == null || e.Rate == null
                ? (double?) null
                : Math.Round(e.Multiplier.Value * e.Rate.Value)
    });
```

Comment: So, I guess... it's not possible to have nice and clean `context.Operations.First();` which would get me full `Operation` entity with all data? I wouldn't even mind using raw SQL for some parts of that query.

Comment: EF is limited, Math.Round is not supported. But you can create your custom function Round. Then it will work without client side evaluation.

Comment: I don't mean those rounding functions. Ok, let's say I have custom function for rounding which works DB side. Now I still don't know how (or if) I would be able to to make those subqueries "default" for those properties. All I want to do is call `var o = ctx.Operations.First();` and `o.Time`, `o.Tariff` should have values. Also if I query `ctx.Plans.Include(p => p.PlanStructures).ThenInclude(s => s.Operations)`, all of those operations should be full. This was working with DB `View`, but as I said, I couldn't link both `Operation` and `OperationView` to one parent entity. (or didn't know how)

Comment: I didn't get that. How Includes are related to this query? `Include` introduced ONLY for loading related entries and it has nothing with original query of the question.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain my intentions well... My initial thoughts were about some "universal" solution which would be able to work in all other queries. So what I need is `Tariff` and `Time` should act like a some kind of virtual column. If I query Operations, it should come with Tariff and Time "automatically" calculated. Same goes if I query Plans and include PlanStructures and Operations - I need those Tariff and Time calculated there aswell.

Comment: Don't do that. You need that only in one-two conrollers. Make custom projection for each appropriate case. Include is the evil for performance if you care about that.